# "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry..." Error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parameters

Basically I am a Winforms guy. Learning ASP.Net and MVC and stuck in a problem.

I have page with name `Calculation`. Contents are as follows

```
<asp:Content ID="aboutContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>
        <%: ViewData["Message"] %>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public ActionResult Calculation(int value)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = String.Format("{0} when squared produces {1}", value, Models.Mathematics.Square(value));
        return View();
    }
```

I pressed `ctrl+5` and reached my homepage. Clicked Calculation page and received an error as

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'value' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Calculation(Int32)' in 'MathSolution.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

I tried passing 
`http://localhost:3670/Home/Calculation/5` and also
`http://localhost:3670/Home/Calculation?value=5`. I am still receiving error. I have also tried placing `HttpPost` on my `Calculation` method in HomeController.cs.

However, if in HomeContoller.cs file Calculation method I place a default value for parameter, then error disappears and I get the default value always.

To be honest, my tutorial is able to make it work but I am not sure whats wrong with my solution. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Do I have to make any changes to IIS on my machine....or it doesn't matter...?

Comment: Are you using MVC with WebForms controls? You might be better off going pure MVC with Razor. It looks like your routing might not be working properly. Check your `RouteConfig.cs`.

Comment: Try changing param name to 'id', like as :  public ActionResult Calculation(int id)... or add route in your global.asax.cs... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155864/asp-net-mvc-passing-parameters-to-the-controller

Comment: I am using Webforms with MVC. I chose `ASP.Net MVC2 Web Application` in visual studio 2010. Well, I cant locate any routeconfig.cs file. And regarding Razor, hmmm, for now I am just following a tutorial to get basics.

Comment: I think @Mate has it - the default routing in MVC uses "id" as the parameter name. You can see this in the Global.asax.cs file - from there, you can change it if you want, or add additional routes, but your simplest solution would just be to use "id".

Comment: Using id is working. But when I click `Calculation` page why I am getting error? I can see in Global.asax.cs file that the parameter is set to Optional. Why am I not getting my default page?

Comment: @Mate: It will be great if you can post the answer and allow me to accept it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution, and not necessarily the best: Try changing param name to 'id'

```
public ActionResult Calculation(int id)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = String.Format("{0} when squared produces {1}", id, Models.Mathematics.Square(id));
            return View();
        }
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155864/asp-net-mvc-passing-parameters-to-the-controller)  for a more precise explanation

Comment: Placing `HttpPost` on top of Calculation methood solved the default page as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You either need give your parameter a default value:

```
public ActionResult Calculation(int value = 0)
```

Or make it a nullable type:

```
public ActionResult Calculation(int? value)
```

Since it is an integer it cannot be null which is what it is when no value specified in the route.

Comment: Thanks Ninlar for your effort. But I think passing default value will just help in avoiding error as I will always get the result based on the default value itself as the real problem will still be there.