# Wrong get data with Crystal reporting

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I am new with  asp.net MVC5, i'm using entity Framework code first. In my controller i have already created folder with Crystal reporting tool and Dataset to get the data with parameter

```
 // GET: Contact
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var Contact = db.Contact.Include(s => s.customer);
        return View(await Contact.ToListAsync());
    }


    // GET: Contact/Report/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExportReport(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Contact Contact = await db.Contact.FindAsync(id);
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report"), "CrystalReport1.rpt"));
        rd.SetDataSource(Contact);
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        try
        {
            Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "Contact.pdf");
        }
        catch { throw; }


    }
```

Can any one help me why i got this error?

> HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request
>   Unzulässige Anforderung
>   Detailed Error Information:
>   Module     ManagedPipelineHandler
>   Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
>   Handler    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
>   Error Code     0x00000000

thanks

Comment: I assume your id is null

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155864/asp-net-mvc-passing-parameters-to-the-controller hope that helps

Comment: what this is means Unzulässige Anforderung?

Comment: Unzulässige Anforderung its mean Unacceptable requirement