# Send multiple parameters from razor to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want send 3 parameters from a view page to an action that need 3 incoming argument like this:

```
  public ActionResult Get_full(int providers_id, int providers_change_request, 
  string persian_name)
    {......}
```

and the view page is like this:

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="insert_log">@item.insert_log</td>
                <td id="persian_name">@item.persian_name</td>
                <td 
     id="providers_change_request_id">@item.providers_change_request_id
                </td>
                <td id="providers_id">@item.providers_id</td>
                <td>

                    <a href="/Default/Get_full">
                          clickme
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
```

please help me how can i do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC -  passing parameters to the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155864/asp-net-mvc-passing-parameters-to-the-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@Url.Action`

in your case, you can call like this. (I believe your controller name is "Default")

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Get_full","Default", new { providers_id= yourId, providers_change_request= yourRequest, persian_name = yourString})">
    clickme
</a>
```

Please mind these information:

- Get_full is your method name in your controller
- Default is your controller
- You have to match param names on Url.Action. Otherwise your method
  can not get the information that you provide.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Many a ways to do this.
1) Assign name to these elements of HTML suppose 
@item.providers_id
and in your action give the same name like below. As many as you want to receive

public ActionResult Get_full(int id)
2) Second method is you can receive in action through Request.form['id'](name of tag or element)
3) Third way to doing this is Request['id'](name of tag inside)
4) Fourth way for make class object of all attribute you want to receive in action and receive action argument.

if you want to send Action to action data put it in ViewBag then receive it in another view or pass it as argument while redirecting to action

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, you can use `TempData` as well. It uses `Session["AnyKey"]` variable to store your data and you can access from `action-to-action` or `controller-to-controller`.

Please refer, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786603/Using-TempData-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 0):

While I accept & learn from the accepted answer, we can also wrap those fields inside the html form. BeginForm() in Html helpers can post the form values when submitting the form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Get_Full", "Default")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Topic</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.insert_log, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.insert_log, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.persian_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.persian_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.providers_change_request_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.providers_change_request_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.providers_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.providers_id)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="GetFullInfo" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```